# Show, that $\sigma$-finite measure on $\sigma$($\mathcal{A}$) may not be $\sigma$-finite on $\mathcal{A}$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let  $(E,M,\mu)$ be a measurable space, $\mu$ a $\sigma$-finite measure, $\mathcal{A}$ an  algebra, such that $\sigma$ ($\mathcal{A}$) = $M$. Show that $\mu$ may not be $\sigma$-finite on $\mathcal{A}$.

Here are my thoughts:

I think we can consider the σ-algebra generated by cylinder sets. But I don't know how to construct a measure in this setting.

Moreover, let $E = \mathbb Q$, $\mathcal M = 2^E$, $\mu$ the counting measure, $\mathcal A = \{\emptyset, \mathbb Q\}$. Then, $μ$ is't $σ$-finite on $\mathcal A$. But I need $σ (\mathcal A) = \mathcal M$. $\mathcal A=\{\emptyset, \mathbb Q\}$ is a $σ$-algebra and wider than what is needed.

Comment: And your thoughts on the problem are? Hint: Taking $E = \Bbb{Q}$ with the counting measure might be helpful.

Comment: I consider, that we can take $\sigma$-algebra generated by cylinder sets. But I don't know, how can construct measure in this cause. I'll try counting measure that is pretty much easier, thank you @PhoemueX

Comment: @PhoemueX 
I have some problems. I take $E$ = $Q$, $M$ = 2$^E$, counting measure $\mu$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ = {$\emptyset$, $Q$}. Then, we have that $\mu$ is't $\sigma$-finite on $\mathcal{A}$. But I need $\sigma$ ($\mathcal{A}$) = $M$. $\mathcal{A}$={$\emptyset$, $Q$} is $\sigma$-algebra and wider than I need.

Comment: You need another algebra. Think about "intervals" in $\Bbb {Q} $.

Comment: Really, this algebra $\mathcal A$={$C\subset \mathbb{Q} \:|\: C\textrm { is finite}$} $\cup$ {$\infty$} is what I need. Thank you, @PhoemueX